# selectInput (dropdown) doesn't show the choice-list (descriptions) but numbers

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app having a tabPanel with a reactive (dynamic) set of dropdowns.

The data for all these dropdowns are coming from a csv file which contains all of the transaction data. While the first 3 dropdowns are showing up the description correctly as the choice list, the fourth dropdown is showing the number but not the description (like 'Buy i case, get 1 case free' etc. which is what the csv file has).

Code for loading the data and rendering the dropdown is as under. Would appreciate pointers to help me resolve this issue.

```
### Getting Reactive Data of Scheme File

SchemeData.actual <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 1000, session, 
                               filePath = "Data/Scheme Data.csv", 
                               readFunc = read.csv
)

### Creating Dropdown for the Scheme

output$SchemeUI <- renderUI({
Mydata_Scheme <- SchemeData()

# Filtering Data Corresponding to Category and SKU
Mydata_Scheme  <- Mydata_Scheme[which(as.character(Mydata_Scheme$Product.DC.C.Category)==input$Category), ]
Mydata_Scheme  <- Mydata_Scheme[which(as.character(Mydata_Scheme$Product.DC.C.Pack)==input$SKU), ]

# Getting Unique number of SKUs
Mydata_Scheme.scheme <- unique(Mydata_Scheme$Promotion.Description)

as <- HTML("")
if(input$SKU=="All") {
  as <- HTML("")
} else {
  as <- selectInput(inputId = "Scheme", label = "Select Scheme", choices = Mydata_Scheme.scheme)      
}

as

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Team,

Just realized that i hadn't tried the very basic transformation when supplying the choice-list to the `selectInput` entity. The following change of code worked like a charm -

```
as <- selectInput(inputId = "Scheme", label = "Select Scheme", choices=c("",as.character(input.variables)))
```

Comment: There's no need to include the "" in c("", as.character(input.variables)) statement. Just set choices=as.character(input.variables)

Comment: Agree. But I also wanted to start with a <blank> option and then read the user input. Hence the additional "".